# ¿Porque no se envian mis datos que recabo de mi formulario?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esta es al imagen de mi codigo del formulario con el cual estoy recabando datos

```
<?php
//Hace conexión con conexión.php
include("conexion.php");
//Declara las variables nombre, apellido, correo
  $Registro= $_POST["Registro"];
  $Ramo= $_POST["Ramo"];
  $Consecutivo= $_POST["Consecutivo"];
  $Fecha= $_POST["Fecha"];
  $RFC= $_POST["RFC"];
  $Nombre_Comercial= $_POST["Nombre_Comercial"];
  $Razon_Social= $_POST["Razon_Social"];
  $Actividad= $_POST["Actividad"];
  $Giro= $_POST["Giro"];
  $Proceso= $_POST["Proceso"];
  $Calle= $_POST["Calle"];
  $Numero= $_POST["Numero"];
  $Colonia= $_POST["Colonia"];
  $Seccion= $_POST["Seccion"];
  $CP= $_POST["CP"];
  $Tel= $_POST["Tel"];
  $Propietario= $_POST["Propietario"];
  $Tel_Prop= $_POST["Tel_Prop"];
  $Domicilio= $_POST["Domicilio"];
//Inserta en la tabla "usuarios" el nombre, el apellido y el correo las variables declaradas anteriormente
  $query="INSERT INTO registro(Registro,Ramo,Consecutivo,Fecha,RFC,Nombre_Comercial,Razon_Social,Actividad,Giro,Proceso,Calle,Numero,Colonia,Seccion,CP,Tel,Propietario,Tel_Prop,Domicilio) VALUES ('$Registro','.$Ramo.','$Consecutivo','.$Fecha.','.$RFC.','.$Nombre_Comercial.','.$Razon_Social.','.$Actividad.','.$Giro.','.$Proceso.','.$Calle.','$Numero','.$Colonia.','.$Seccion.','$CP','$Tel','.$Propietario.','$Tel_Prop','.$Domicilio.')";
//Abre conexión
  $resultado= $conexion->query($query);
//Si hay conexión los datos se llevarán hacía la tabla
  if($resultado){
    header("Location: index2.php");
  }
  //Si no hay conexión aparecerá lo siguiente
  else{
    echo "Insercion no exitosa";
  }

?>
```

Este es el codigo que uso en php para hacer el insert de los datos, el problema esta en que cuando presiono el boton enviar, la base no marca ningun error, y en teoria envia los datos a mi BD, pero cuando quiero visualizarla en phpmyadmin no se ve nada, solo 0 en aquellos campos que fueron definidos como int, pero en aquellos que son varchar no se registra nada

[image: Esta es al visualizacion que obtengo de phpmyadmin, por lo que quisiera que alguien me explicara cual es mi error, porque a pesar de que la conexion a la base de datos es exitosa o al menos no marca error, no puedo visualizar los datos recabados en el formulario anterior]

Comment: Por mas que lo intente no puedo hacer que los datos recabados en el formulario se envien a mi base de datos, mi conexion no marca error ni nada lo cual se me hace extraño

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Answer (score 1):

En la imagen que publicaste se ve poco. Si pudieras poner el código textual sería mejor. Pero de lo que puedo ver observo que no coinciden los tag's **name** con los índices del `$_POST` en el Php.

Entiendo que en la línea:

```
$Registro= $_POST["Registro"];
```

Hace alusión a este input:

```
<input type="text" name="No. de Registro" placeholder="Escriba el número" value=""><br><br>
```

Si así fuera, la variable `$registro` debería ser igual a `$_POST['No. de Registro']` para obtener el valor del *input*.

Y otro problema que veo es en esta línea:

```
$query="INSERT INTO registro(Registro,Ramo,Consecutivo,Fecha,RFC,Nombre_Comercial,Razon_Social,Actividad,Giro,Proceso,Calle,Numero,Colonia,Seccion,CP,Tel,Propietario,Tel_Prop,Domicilio) VALUES ('$Registro','.$Ramo.','$Consecutivo','.$Fecha.','.$RFC.','.$Nombre_Comercial.','.$Razon_Social.','.$Actividad.','.$Giro.','.$Proceso.','.$Calle.','$Numero','.$Colonia.','.$Seccion.','$CP','$Tel','.$Propietario.','$Tel_Prop','.$Domicilio.')";
```

Estás agregando puntos innecesarios. Imagino que por equivocación al intentar concatenar dos cadenas. Pero no es necesario concatenarlas. Deberías eliminar los puntos.

Así debería quedar:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO registro (Registro, Ramo, Consecutivo, Fecha, RFC, Nombre_Comercial, Razon_Social, Actividad, Giro, Proceso, Calle, Numero, Colonia, Seccion, CP, Tel, Propietario, Tel_Prop, Domicilio) VALUES ('$Registro', '$Ramo', '$Consecutivo', '$Fecha', '$RFC', '$Nombre_Comercial', '$Razon_Social', '$Actividad', '$Giro', '$Proceso', '$Calle', '$Numero', '$Colonia', '$Seccion', '$CP', '$Tel', '$Propietario', '$Tel_Prop', '$Domicilio')";
```

Y otra cosa. Si no marca ningún error deberías agregar esto en la primera línea de tu archivo php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICES);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Esto es útil para depurar. Te sirve para que te imprima en pantalla si ocurre algún error.